# Matrix multiplication in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, linear-algebra, sbcl

I am writing the program in CL (with SBCL 1.2.15) that uses linear algebra. During the course of execution, it often multiplies a matrix by a vector.

Profiler showed that most of the time (80%) the program spends doing exactly that, multiplying matrix by vector. It also shows that this function does lots of consing (80,000,000 for ~100 calls for 100x100 matrices), which triggers GC as well. Having done something similar in F# (that has a benefit of static type-checking, but otherwise does not usually outperform SBCL), F# program runs 10 times faster.

Am I doing it wrong?

```
(defun matrix-mul (matrix vector dest)
  "Multiply MATRIX by VECTOR putting the result into DEST.
Optimized for DOUBLE-FLOAT vectors and matrices"
  (declare (type (array double-float (* *)) matrix)
           (type (vector double-float *) vector dest)
           (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))
  (destructuring-bind (rows cols) (array-dimensions matrix)
   (dotimes (i rows)
     (setf (aref dest i)
           (loop for j below cols sum (the double-float
                                           (* (aref matrix i j) (aref vector j))))))))
```

PS. I have also tried using DOTIMES instead of inner LOOP - no difference

PPS. Next option can be using BLAS from CL, but (i) I am not looking forward to making it work on Windows, (ii) will need marshaling matrices/vectors back and forth.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at lisp-matrix. It implements matrix functions which calls into BLAS and LAPACK. You will probably see that they are much faster. In particular as your matrixes grow in size.

Comment: @EliasMårtenson The reason I'm doing it directly in CL is because I don't want to bind to BLAS. The size I'm working with (~100) doesn't warrant heavy artillery, also binding to BLAS from Windows (Cygwin or MGWin) is another story.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual problem is that float arithmetic, here with double-floats, (independent of the surrounding code like matrix multiplication) conses.

Generally the first thing to do with SBCL in such cases:

**Put the code into a file and compile it**

The compiler will then output a lot of optimization problems, given that one compiles for speed. You would then need to examine the notes and see what you can do.

Here for example the `LOOP` sum lacks type information.

There is actually a `LOOP` syntax to declare the type of the sum variable. I don't know if SBCL takes advantage of that:

```
(loop repeat 10
      sum 1.0d0 of-type double-float)
```

SBCL 1.3.0 on 32bit ARM for your code:

```
* (compile-file "/tmp/test.lisp")

; compiling file "/tmp/test.lisp" (written 13 DEC 2015 11:34:26 AM):
; compiling (DEFUN MATRIX-MUL ...)
; file: /tmp/test.lisp
```

1)

```
; in: DEFUN MATRIX-MUL
;     (SETF (AREF DEST I)
;             (LOOP FOR J BELOW COLS
;                   SUM (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT (* # #))))
; --> LET* FUNCALL SB-C::%FUNCALL (SETF AREF)
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-SET ARRAY SB-INT:INDEX SB-C::NEW-VALUE)
;
; note: unable to
;   avoid runtime dispatch on array element type
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a (VECTOR DOUBLE-FLOAT), not a SIMPLE-ARRAY.
```

2)

```
;     (AREF MATRIX I J)
; --> LET*
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-REF ARRAY SB-INT:INDEX)
;
; note: unable to
;   avoid runtime dispatch on array element type
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a (ARRAY DOUBLE-FLOAT (* *)), not a SIMPLE-ARRAY.
```

3)

```
;     (AREF VECTOR J)
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:HAIRY-DATA-VECTOR-REF ARRAY SB-INT:INDEX)
;
; note: unable to
;   avoid runtime dispatch on array element type
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a (VECTOR DOUBLE-FLOAT), not a SIMPLE-ARRAY.
```

4)

```
;     (LOOP FOR J BELOW COLS
;           SUM (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT (* (AREF MATRIX I J) (AREF VECTOR J))))
; --> BLOCK LET SB-LOOP::WITH-SUM-COUNT LET SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY TAGBODY SETQ THE
; ==>
;   (+ #:LOOP-SUM-8 (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT (* (AREF MATRIX I J) (AREF VECTOR J))))
;
; note: unable to
;   optimize
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a NUMBER, not a (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT).
;
; note: unable to
;   optimize
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a NUMBER, not a (COMPLEX DOUBLE-FLOAT).
```

5)

```
; --> BLOCK LET SB-LOOP::WITH-SUM-COUNT LET SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY TAGBODY WHEN IF
; --> >= OR LET IF OR THE = IF
; ==>
;   (= SB-C::X SB-C::Y)
;
; note: unable to open code because: The operands might not be the same type.
```

6)

```
;     (DOTIMES (I ROWS)
;       (SETF (AREF DEST I)
;               (LOOP FOR J BELOW COLS
;                     SUM (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT #))))
; --> DO BLOCK LET TAGBODY UNLESS IF >= IF
; ==>
;   (< SB-C::X SB-C::Y)
;
; note: forced to do static-fun Two-arg-< (cost 53)
;       unable to do inline fixnum comparison (cost 4) because:
;       The second argument is a INTEGER, not a FIXNUM.
;       unable to do inline (signed-byte 32) comparison (cost 6) because:
;       The second argument is a INTEGER, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 32).
;       etc.
```

7)

```
;     (LOOP FOR J BELOW COLS
;           SUM (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT (* (AREF MATRIX I J) (AREF VECTOR J))))
; --> BLOCK LET SB-LOOP::WITH-SUM-COUNT LET SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY TAGBODY WHEN IF
; --> >= OR LET > IF
; ==>
;   (> SB-C::X SB-C::Y)
;
; note: forced to do static-fun Two-arg-> (cost 53)
;       unable to do inline fixnum comparison (cost 4) because:
;       The second argument is a REAL, not a FIXNUM.
;       unable to do inline (signed-byte 32) comparison (cost 6) because:
;       The second argument is a REAL, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 32).
;       etc.
```

8)

```
; --> BLOCK LET SB-LOOP::WITH-SUM-COUNT LET SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY TAGBODY SETQ THE
; ==>
;   (+ #:LOOP-SUM-8 (THE DOUBLE-FLOAT (* (AREF MATRIX I J) (AREF VECTOR J))))
;
; note: forced to do static-fun Two-arg-+ (cost 53)
;       unable to do inline float arithmetic (cost 2) because:
;       The first argument is a NUMBER, not a DOUBLE-FLOAT.
;       The result is a (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES DOUBLE-FLOAT
;                                                                &REST T).
;
; note: doing float to pointer coercion (cost 13), for:
;       the second argument of static-fun Two-arg-+
;
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 10 notes
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I changed `ARRAY` and `VECTOR` declarations to `SIMPLE-ARRAY`, added type declaration for `COLS` and `ROWS` and changed the summation loop to `DOTIMES` summing into a temporary `DOUBLE-FLOAT` variable. Now the speed is comparable with F#!

Answer (score 1):

With current sbcl (2.0.1) there are still optimization warnings with the code above.

Change to:

double-float:

```
(defun matrix-mul (matrix vector dest)
  "Multiply MATRIX by VECTOR putting the result into DEST.
Optimized for DOUBLE-FLOAT vectors and matrices"
  (declare (type (simple-array double-float (* *)) matrix)
           (type (simple-array double-float *) vector dest)
           (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))
  (destructuring-bind (rows cols) (array-dimensions matrix)
    (declare (fixnum rows cols))
    (dotimes (i rows)
      (let ((sum 0.0d0))
        (declare (double-float sum))
        (setf (aref dest i)
              (progn
                (dotimes (j cols)
                  (incf sum (* (aref matrix i j) (aref vector j))))
                sum)))))
  dest)
```

single-float:

```
(defun matrix-mul (matrix vector dest)
  "Multiply MATRIX by VECTOR putting the result into DEST.
Optimized for SINGLE-FLOAT vectors and matrices"
  (declare (type (simple-array single-float (* *)) matrix)
           (type (simple-array single-float *) vector dest)
           (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))
  (destructuring-bind (rows cols) (array-dimensions matrix)
    (declare (fixnum rows cols))
    (dotimes (i rows)
      (let ((sum 0.0))
        (declare (single-float sum))
        (setf (aref dest i)
              (progn
                (dotimes (j cols)
                  (incf sum (* (aref matrix i j) (aref vector j))))
                sum)))))
  dest)
```